# Powershell multiple AddParameter C#

Tags: c#, powershell, parameters

I run a PowerShell from within a C# form application. I want to add multiple parameters to my PowerShell command.

But when I enter a second `AddParameter` call, it failed with the error:

> System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException

Code:

```
PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-NetAdapter");
shell.AddParameter("name", "Ethernet*");
shell.AddParameter("InterfaceIndex", "5");

foreach (PSObject result in shell.Invoke())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-24}{1}", result.Members["Name"].Value,
                                    result.Members["InterfaceDescription"].Value);
} // End foreach.
```

It looks like it only accepts 1 parameter.

There is also a `AddParameters`, but I'm not able to get this working.

Anyone got any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually use `name` and `InterfaceIndex` at the same time with the `Get-NetAdapter` cmdlet. This is because they belong to different Parameter Sets and as a result must be used separately.

To see details of the Parameter Sets for that cmdlet see here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130867(v=wps.630).aspx

Or use `Get-Help Get-NetAdapter` in PowerShell.

However if you are still having issues adding parameters when using ones that are permitted in the same parameter set, you could try adding both parameters as a single command, like this (using `name` and `throttlelimit` as an example, as they are permitted in the same Parameter Set: `ByName` for `Get-NetAdapter`):

```
PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-NetAdapter")
                                      .AddParameter("name", "Ethernet*")
                                      .AddParameter("ThrottleLimit", 5);
```

Or alternatively you can use a dictionary of parameter names and values:

```
IDictionary parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
parameters.Add("name", "Ethernet*");
parameters.Add("ThrottleLimit", 5);

PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-NetAdapter")
   .AddParameters(parameters)
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn614674(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thx for the quick reply !
I have tried it and they both ends up with the same error message.
the exception message is:
{"Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."}

Comment: Ah, that's a PowerShell error. It is telling you that you can't use both "name" and "InterfaceIndex" together as they belong to different parameter sets. You can see the Parameter Sets here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130867(v=wps.630).aspx or in PowerShell via `get-help get-netadapter`. The cmdlet isn't designed to retrieve network adapters by both index and name at the same time, it needs to be one or the other.