Retrieving a PSObject value from embedded script in VB.NET
I have this code in an existing app trying to check if the email for a new group is already present in ExchangeOnline:
Private Sub _save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _save.Click
    Dim newGroupName As String = _groupName.Text
    If CheckPrimarySmtpExOnline(newGroupName) Then
        ' ...
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CheckPrimarySmtpExOnline(newGroupName As String) As Boolean
    Dim _ExOnlineAppId As String = ""
    Dim _ExOnlineCert As String = ""
    Dim _result As Boolean = False

    Try
        Dim initialSessionState As InitialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()
        Dim modules As String() = {"ExchangeOnlineManagement"}
        initialSessionState.ImportPSModule(modules)

        Dim runspace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState)
        Dim powershell As System.Management.Automation.PowerShell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create()
        powershell.Runspace = runspace
        runspace.Open()
        Dim myScript As String = """
                    Param (
                            [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
                            [string]$ExOnlineAppID,
                            [string]$ExOnlineCert,
                            [string]$name
                    )
                    try {
                        Set-Executionpolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -Force
                        $splat = @{
                            appid = $ExOnlineAppID
                            Organization = 'myorg.onmicrosoft.com'
                            CertificateThumbprint = $ExOnlineCert
                            CommandName = @('Get-Recipient', 'Get-Mailbox', 'New-Mailbox', 'Add-MailboxPermission', 'Remove-MailboxPermission')
                            Showbanner =  $false
                            ErrorAction = 'Stop'
                        }
                        Connect-ExchangeOnline @splat

                        $Recipient = Get-Recipient $name@domain.com | Select PrimarySmtpAddress
                    }
                    catch {
                        $PSItem | Export-CLIXML 'D:\..\error.xml'
                    }
                    
                    Return $Recipient.PrimarySmtpAddress

                    Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false                        
            """
        powershell.AddScript(myScript)
        powershell.AddParameter("ExonlineAppID", _ExOnlineAppId)
        powershell.AddParameter("ExOnlineCert", _ExOnlineCert)
        powershell.AddParameter("name", newGroupName)
        Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = powershell.Invoke(Nothing)
        If results.Count > 0 Then
            Dim firstResult As PSObject = results(0)
            If firstResult IsNot Nothing Then
                _result = True
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Error checking primary SMTP address in Exchange Online", ex)
    End Try
End Function

I tested the PowerShell script separately and it does correctly retrieve the PrimarySmtpAddress (if present).
The issue is trying to call it from VB.Net and get the result as part of a PSObject variable... I'm not able to find the value for primarysmtpaddress in this PSObject. Instead, I see this:

So the validation I'm doing always finds something, always returns true. I tried some variations but the return types are always the same.
How can get I get just PrimarySmtpAddress from this result, so I can correctly get a True/False result for my function?

As an aside: your Return statement prevents the Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false call from ever executing.

This is just connecting to MS Graph. If it were me, I would make the VB connect to MS Graph directly. It's not that difficult, and MS has a number of examples. Even if you can't use the NuGet sdk package to make it easy, it's still just rest requests.

For the proper way to Set-Executionpolicy see the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76398401/10024425. The following may be of interest as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44131280/10024425


You should be able to use the generic form of the .Invoke() method to specify the result type you expect:
Untested:
Dim results As Collection(Of Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress) = _
  powershell.Invoke(Of Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress)(Nothing)

' ...

Dim firstResult As Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress = results(0)

Note:

To be able to reference type Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress, your project must reference the relevant NuGet package, which I think is Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.

Alternatively - assuming you know the members of this type (e.g. .Domain, .IsValidAddress) - you can try to access them dynamically, along the following lines (also untested):
Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = powershell.Invoke(Nothing)

' ...

Dim firstResult As PSObject = results(0)

' Try to access property .IsValidAddress dynamically,
' .BaseObject is the PSObject property that contains the
' wrapped object.
firstResult.BaseObject.IsValidAddress




Thanks for the quick update. What nuget should I need to use for Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress?

@kaz00ie, please see my update, but note that I'm only guessing.

@kaz00ie If you're free to add NuGet packages, you should add the MS Graph API package to connect to Graph directly from VB, and bypass the powershell invocation completely.
